# how to implement addOnScrollListener to recycler view with id as rvChannel

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I am trying to load more data when the recycler view with id: `rvChannel` is scrolled down to the bottom. But the issue I am facing is: the `onScrolled()` and `onScrollStateChanged()` of `addOnScrollListener` of `rvChannel` is fired only first time the view is rendered, after then no matter how many numbers of time you scroll up or down, the methods (`onScrolled()` and `onScrollStateChanged()`) are not getting triggered. I have attached the supporting layout below. In case of any doubt please lemme know so that I can provide a further understanding of the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvTimeBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />


        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvChannel"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/row_channel" />

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">


                        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/rvProgramme"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                            tools:listitem="@layout/row_programme" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

The java code is as follows:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnLoadMoreListener {
    ActivityHomeBinding binding;
    HomeViewModel viewModel;
    private ChannelAdapter adapter;
    private ProgrammeAdapter programmeAdapter;
    private TimeBarAdapter timeBarAdapter;
    private int serialSublistEndIndex = 30;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_home);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        timeBarAdapter = new TimeBarAdapter();
        timeBarAdapter.setTimeBarList(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.timeBarList)));
        adapter = new ChannelAdapter(this);
        programmeAdapter = new ProgrammeAdapter();
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        binding.rvChannel.setLayoutManager(llm);
        binding.rvChannel.setAdapter(adapter);
        binding.rvProgramme.setAdapter(programmeAdapter);
        binding.rvTimeBar.setAdapter(timeBarAdapter);
        viewModel.fetchChannelData();
        viewModel.channelLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<List<ChannelData>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<ChannelData> channelData) {
                if (viewModel.channelLiveData.getValue() != null &&
                        viewModel.channelLiveData.getValue().subList(0, 40).size() >= 0) {
                    viewModel.fetchSerialData();
                }
            }
        });
        viewModel.serialResponseLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<List<SerialResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<SerialResponse> responses) {
                if (responses != null && responses.size() > 0) {
                    viewModel.setSerialMutableList(viewModel.channelLiveData.getValue().subList(0, 40));
                    adapter.setChannelDataList(viewModel.channelLiveData.getValue().subList(0, 40));
                    programmeAdapter.setChannelDataList(viewModel.channelLiveData.getValue().subList(0, 40), viewModel);
                }
            }
        });

        binding.rvChannel.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                Log.v("onScrolled", "onScrolled");
            }
        });
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadMore(int position) {
        adapter.setChannelDataList(viewModel.channelLiveData.getValue().subList(position + 1, position + 11));
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case you should provide some of your java code as scrolling logic is implemented there

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post, kindly have a look at it

Comment: you can use  `if(dy > 0){ /*get refresh data*/ }` inside on scrolled. You might also add a `isLoading` during getting refreshed data

Comment: perhaps the scrollView scrolling instead of the recyclerView? Be aware that probably you will have a performance / memory issue with this EPG implementation, the items inside the recyclerView won't be recycled (because it is nested inside a scrollView).

Comment: cylon: can you then suggest me how to implement the load more functionality for the above task

Comment: Sp4Rx: I will be able to use if(dy > 0){ /*get refresh data*/ }, only when the method gets triggered. The onScrolled or onScrollStateChanged is being called the only first time, after then, it is not getting called ever.